# FFmpeg C# Video Conversion

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

On the click of a button I am trying to trim down an MP4 videos between two certain times with the use of FFmpeg C# Wrapper. My code is as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CAVConverter converter = new CAVConverter();
        converter.LogPath = @"C:\Users\Rachel\Desktop\Log.txt";           
        converter.InputOptions.TimeStart = 5000000; //Start time to trim, unit is um(micro second)
        converter.OutputOptions.TimeLength = 3000000; //Time length to trim, unit is um(micro second)
        converter.AddTask(@"C:\\Users\\Rachel\\Desktop\\Tennis\\Serve.mp4",
                                      @"C:\\Users\\Rachel\\Desktop\\Tennis\\ServeCut.mp4");            
        converter.StartAndWait();            
    }
```

The code compiles and runs however the Log.txt file returns the following:

`Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 180000.00 (180000/1) -> 90000.00 (180000/2)
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\\Users\\Rachel\\Desktop\\Tennis\\Serve.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: isom3gp4
      Duration: 00:00:38.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10193 kb/s
        Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x720, 9982 kb/s, PAR 65536:65536 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
        Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: libfaad, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 128 kb/s
    [mpeg4 @ 09762200]removing common factors from framerate
    [mpeg4 @ 09762200]timebase not supported by mpeg 4 standard
    Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\\Users\\Rachel\\Desktop\\Tennis\\ServeCut.mp4':
        Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
        Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: libfaac, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0.0 -> #0.0 (Video)
      Stream #0.1 -> #0.1 (Audio)
    Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 (Video) - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
    Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 (Video) - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height`

I don't know much about FFmpeg or videos, so can anybody help me? 
Many thanks

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show the actual `ffmpeg` command being issued and the complete `ffmpeg` console output from that command? (I'm assuming you're executing the `ffmpeg` binary.)

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I'm using this wrapper [link](http://www.ffmpeg-csharp.com/) so i'm not sure it executes the binary?

Comment: First part tells you that there is framerate inconsistency between vid and container. The latter says there's an error while opening encoder for output so try checking your params, probably you have too few options set

Answer (score 0):

You can use commands like this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string fileName, string arguments);
```

or you can use the exe from the official site from ffmpeg and pass the argumentsto them.